# Zlib dictionary training

Tags: linux

I have what is possibly a unique problem to solve
I need to create a compress/decompress which works on short strings (sentences) lets say 100 bytes
The strings contain a limited number of unique ASCII characters, in fact a total of 41 possible.
The strings also contain a relatively small set of possible to substrings

I want to train zlib to create a dictionary, based upon the legal set of characters, and the frequently occurring substrings

Ideally I would want to create a dictionary by providing a huge dataset of possible sentences, but excliding the illegal characters

Any suggestions?
Thx

Comment: Maybe this will help? https://facebook.github.io/zstd/